# ionic 5 iOS app stuck on Splash Screen with no error logs

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I'm trying to build my ionic iOS mobile app which based on cordova-ios 6.1.0 and ios 13.6. My app gets stuck on the Splash screen and the following are the XCode logs. I'm stuck in this issue for days and still no luck.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
2020-11-13 21:04:22.980476+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.0 is starting.
2020-11-13 21:04:22.980827+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-11-13 21:04:23.469793+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2020-11-13 21:04:23.481714+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.481996+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "AutoInjectCordova" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.482185+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "AudioCanMix" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.509558+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "WKSuspendInBackground" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.509790+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.793406+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Kiraly Fitness
2020-11-13 21:04:23.793672+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-11-13 21:04:23.793887+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-11-13 21:04:23.909218+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.909750+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "AllowLinkPreview" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.912102+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.912284+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-11-13 21:04:23.912457+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Using Ionic WKWebView
2020-11-13 21:04:23.913324+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][console] 0.169992ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.913740+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.169992ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.916924+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Unlimited access to network resources
2020-11-13 21:04:23.917392+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Unlimited access to network resources
2020-11-13 21:04:23.917626+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 3.692985ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.918000+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.177979ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.922489+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 4.276037ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.925343+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 2.597094ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.934488+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.934704+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2020-11-13 21:04:23.935362+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.937372+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-13 21:04:23.938561+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 6.577015ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.943178+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][file] 3.783941ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.944279+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][paypalmobile] 0.138044ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.950443+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][cdvwkwebviewfilexhr] 5.802989ms
2020-11-13 21:04:23.950708+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 37.629008ms
2020-11-13 21:04:24.086768+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2020-11-13 21:04:24.174174+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] app become active
2020-11-13 21:04:24.557624+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Device FCM Token: dqJks6p7GEgHt-2EczLTFY:APA91bGDsY-7tCz4TGoerUxtqREWNoZW_ZTPcIwUDcn6b0D0AArlJhLjn0thhr1MXSzkL-IB01-TSFcx4F8QPSJfQFQA5GoxdlYtqqrqR22ILEEmnjCRw2zSZIDL_vmTTshY22CQJe5I
2020-11-13 21:04:29.683167+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Cordova view ready
2020-11-13 21:04:30.094023+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] start Js Event Bridge
2020-11-13 21:04:30.136804+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] FCM: has been created
2020-11-13 21:04:30.137898+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] FCM: Ready!
2020-11-13 21:04:30.138138+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 3266 ms
2020-11-13 21:04:30.138519+0530 Kiraly Fitness[9007:161922] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 3191 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after trying so many ways, I was able to solve the issue.

I have solved the issue by running the below commands to my **project directory**:

`npm install`

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

`pod repo update`

`ionic cordova platform add ios@5.1.0`

`cordova plugin update cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest`

then I add the following to my config.xml under ios platform

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

**do not add**
*`<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />`*

**and again in project directory,**

`ionic cordova prepare ios`

`cordova build ios`